# Show/Hide DIV sections based on radio boxes

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

I'm trying to rework several forms and there are several sections where I have a typical "Was xxxx Required?" Yes/No radio boxes. If they choose YES I want the box below to open up requiring them to enter more info. I'd like to use one JQuery function if I could that would work for each of those rather than a separate function for each question needing it.

I also have a question where they choose whether the person involved is an Employee or Guest. Thanks to a lot of good posts here I was able to figure out Hiding the Guest DIV until selected but I haven't figured out yet how to do the same for the Employee DIV, and I just found out I need to add a 3rd set of questions for a Vendor.

This is the working code that shows the Guest section

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("div.desc").hide();
   $("input[name$='Victim']").click(function() {
    var test = $(this).val();
      $("div.desc").hide();
      $("#" + test).show();
  });
});
```

Along with

```
<p>
   Who was involved in this incident? &nbsp &nbsp
    <input name="Victim" type="radio" value="Guest" required >Guest 
     &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <input name="Victim" type="radio" value="Employee" > Employee 
    &nbsp; &nbsp;

  <div id="Guest" class="desc">
  <p>
     Some questions here ...
```

Can anyone point me along to getting the additional code working? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unclear what you mean.. if you have a div with the id of `Employee` and one for `Vendor` and add the vendor radio button.... the code works fine....

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("div.desc").hide();
   $("input[name$='Victim']").click(function() {
    var test = $(this).val();
      $("div.desc").hide();
      $("#" + test).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3> Who was involved in this incident? </h3>

<p><label><input name="Victim" type="radio" value="Guest" required >Guest </label></p>

<p><label><input name="Victim" type="radio" value="Employee" > Employee </label</p>
  
  <p><label><input name="Victim" type="radio" value="Vendor" > Vendor</label></p>
  

  <div id="Guest" class="desc">
  <p><strong>Guest</strong> questions here ...</p>
   </div>

  <div id="Employee" class="desc">
  <p><strong>Employee</strong> questions here ...</p>
   </div>

  <div id="Vendor" class="desc">
  <p><strong>Vendor</strong> questions here ...</p>
   </div>
```

Comment: I'm so green on java I didn't pick up on that. Is there a particular reason you use <label> in your code? And is there a way to adapt the same function to all the "IF SO...EXPLAIN" questions without creating a function for each?

Comment: The label allows a user to click the actual **word** as well as the radio button to "check" it. Small thing, but makes usability so much better. No clue what you mean by the second part of that comment.. if all the questions are identical.. do you really need 3 divs to show/hide then???

Comment: There's several sets of questions that only apply to the type of report so I need to hide what doesn't apply. My 2nd question was about triggering the "other" or "please explain" textbox on questions that have them. I.e. What type of accident, slip, fall, cut, burn, other... If other please explain. I'd like to hide the extra textbox unless they click other and then make it required

Comment: Well it would essentially be the same code.. just modified to target the proper elements. Not going to write everything for you... StackOverflow is not a code writing service. All the pieces are in this answer, they can easily be adapted to fit that use.

Comment: I made a lot of progress on it today and I think I worked out modifying it to show the extra boxes. Next thing I have to work out is the validation to require those boxes if they're triggered. Thanks